# Question on applying Jensen inequality on logarithm of a sum

Tags: logarithms, jensen-inequality

I am confused by the meaning of the $t \in (0,1)$ parameter in Jensen's inequality $$ f( tx_1+(1-t)x_2) \le tf(x_1)+(1-t)f(x_2) $$ When I apply this to the logarithm $$ \log( tx_1+(1-t)x_2) \ge t \log(x_1)+(1-t) \log(x_2).$$ Does this mean the convex version of the inequality does not hold for $$ \log( x_1+x_2) \le \log(x_1)+ \log(x_2)?$$ Are there any results for the relation of the quantities on the left and the right si de of the last inequality?

Comment: Not Jensen's just the convex inequality. But logarithm is concave...

Comment: @zwim so the last relation given is incorrect?

Comment: Inequality is reversed, i.e. use $\ge$ insteald of $\le$.

Comment: @zwim Are you sure? I just tried by example $x_1=2, x_2=1$ vs $x_1=2, x_2=3$, reverses the relation. So this does not hold in general.

Comment: Oh sorry I overviewed your mistake. If you take $t\in[0,1]$ then you have $f(\frac{x_1+x_2}2)\ge \frac 12f(x_1)+\frac 12f(x_2)$ for concave function for $t=\frac 12$. I.e the midpoint on the segement joining $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$ is below the curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality you want to have $$\log(x_1+x_2)\leq \log(x_1)+\log(x_2)$$ is equivalent to $$x_1+x_2\leq x_1x_2$$ so it holds whenever the latter one holds, for example when $x_1,x_2\geq 2$. Jensen has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 1):

The correct inequality is $$ \log( tx_1+(1-t)x_2) \ge t \log(x_1)+(1-t) \log(x_2).$$
In particular we have $$ \log( \frac {x_1+x_2} 2) \ge \frac 1 2 (\log(x_1)+ \log(x_2)).$$

Your last in equality fails when  $x_1=x_2=\frac 1  2$.

Comment: Can we extend this inequality to summation of series, say $\log(1+x_1) + \log(1+x_2) + \log(1+x_3)+...$?